# GCP flexible environment: Configure app.yaml to run multiple services

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have configured two services which one of them is the default. But when consulting the `https://gcpdev.company.com/one` service through DNS, it cannot reach the project files. For example:

If I type directly this url, 500 error returns:

```
https://gcpdev.company.com/vendor-es2017.65ff9b5300ddf6707a5c.js
```

The correct one that opens the file is:

```
https://gcpdev.company.com/one/vendor-es2017.65ff9b5300ddf6707a5c.js
```

There is something wrong with my configs? these are the files for `default` project:

dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
  - url: "gcpdev.company.com/one/*"
    service: default
  - url: "gcpdev.company.com/two/*"
    service: two-ui
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12    
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /one/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|less|json|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|scss|css|js|ico|svg)(|\.map))$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*)(|\.map)

  - url: /one/assets/data/appConfig.json
    static_files: dist/assets/data/appConfig.json
    upload: dist/assets/data/appConfig.json

  - url: /one/(.*)
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

For `two-ui` project I have the same `dispatch.yaml` and similar `app.yaml`:

```
 runtime: nodejs12        
 service: two-ui
    
 handlers:
   - url: /two/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|less|json|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|scss|css|js|ico|svg)(|\.map))$
     static_files: dist/\1
     upload: dist/(.*)(|\.map)
    
   - url: /two/assets/data/appConfig.json
     static_files: dist/assets/data/appConfig.json
     upload: dist/assets/data/appConfig.json
    
   - url: /two/(.*)
     static_files: dist/index.html
     upload: dist/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dispatch rules mentions that you have to use either:

- `gcpdev.company.com/one/*`
- `gcpdev.company.com/two/*`

Then, is expected that calls to `gcpdev.company.com/*` fails. There isn´t any rule that dictates how to behave with that pattern.

About:

> The correct one that opens the file is:
> `https://gcpdev.company.com/one/vendor-es2017.65ff9b5300ddf6707a5c.js`

It´s well worth to take a look into the [Examples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#example):

For instance:

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    service: default**strong text**
```

You might need to add something similar to the above mentioned, if you want to serve static files without `/one/*` and `/two/*` patterns.

About how to serve the static files on your services, checking [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) is the next step. My suggestion is to focus first in the  `dispatcher` and as a second step the Handlers in the `app.yaml`.